# Cant convert LINQ Query var to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datatable

I have the following code:

```
var _permiso = from P in _db.clsPermiso
               select P;

var _pagina = from P in _db.clsPagina.AsEnumerable()
              select P;

var _perfil = from P in _db.clsPerfil
              select P;

IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from permiso in _permiso.AsEnumerable()
            join perfil in _perfil.AsEnumerable()
                on permiso.ID equals perfil.ID
            join pagina in _pagina.AsEnumerable()
                on permiso.ID equals pagina.ID
            where (permiso.Acceso == true) && (permiso.Perfil.ID == Convert.ToInt32(strIDPerfil))
            select pagina;
```

I've been gathering some info on the MSDN page, and it tells me to use `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and then, asign that `query` variable into a DataTable var like this:

`DataTable _dtResult = query.CopyToDataTable();`

But im getting the error at the `select pagina` statement:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.clsPagina>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Thx in advice

Comment: its a Class that I'm getting from MVC3
`public class MyAppDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<clsPagina> clsPagina { get; set;}
    }`

Comment: It didnt, It gave me the following error `Error 1 Cannot convert type 'MyApp.Models.clsPagina' to 'System.Data.DataRow'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting enumerables does not necessarily use the implicit conversions that the base types use.  You will likely have to explicitly cast the result "pagina" as a DataRow in your LINQ query.

Not knowing your class/type definitions, I'm only guessing, but I believe you want your last line of your LINQ query to be:

```
select (DataRow)pagina;
```

Is there a specific reason you want the result as more primitive?

Comment: Already try that cast, it gives me the following error `Error 1 Cannot convert type 'MyApp.Models.clsPagina' to 'System.Data.DataRow'`

Comment: OK, and now reading your other comments, I bet you're getting this data from an Entity Framework class? EF is not ADO.NET. They are completely different ways of accessing data.

Can you give us a link to the MSDN page you're reading?  I think you're trying to merge two disparate technologies.

Comment: I needed in a DataTable to loop it in a Foreach, idk if I should use a List instead...

Comment: I'm using a accesing the data on SQL Server 2008, shouldn't be an error on that...
[Here is the link to the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx)

Comment: You can loop through with Foreach on any IEnumerable<>. If you plan on doing it multiple times, or removing some of the elements later, then you can put in a mutable structure like a List. If you just need to foreach on it once, then change "IEnumerable<DataRow> query =" to "var query =" and accept the IEnumerable interface.

Comment: @Cuartico, the page you linked to is about Linq-to-DataSet. Your models are Linq-to-Sql (or EF), a completely different domain.

Comment: Anthony is right on the money.  ADO.NET is fine, EF is fine, but they are different and cannot be mixed/matched.

Comment: The link was giving a close idea for the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but i think I'll just loop it with IEnumerable<T> like @WesleyLong said, I'm losing too much time and I need to solve this, even if I wanted (preffer) to use a DataTable...

Comment: @Cuartico, why would you prefer to use a `DataTable`? You have a sequence of strongly typed models, what is driving you to want to use a weakly-typed DataTable? Unless you're using an API that specifically requires a table, I'd certainly prefer the models.

Comment: I'm kinda used to work with DataTable/DataSet/DataRow, but true, I'm using strongly typed models, its better to use lists in this case. Thank you both for your great help, I'm already finishing the foreach!